# Как в bash-скрипте реализовать триггер на наличие файлов определенного типа?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Необходимо реализовать скрипт, который проводил бы создание бекапов. На приведенной схеме ниже накинул то, как я это вижу логически. Вопрос в реализации: не имею представления, каким образом в скрипте задать триггер на наличие файлов определенного типа (имя/расширение). Не могли бы подсказать возможные решения? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит триггер в данном случае, скрипт будет постоянно работать?

Comment: *имя/расширение* это просто строки, их можно сравнить с нужной строкой через `[[ "" == "" ]]`.

Comment: @DaniilLoban да, скрипт должен работать раз в раз в нн-ое время

Comment: Я правильно понял? Ты щас придумал `rdiff-backup`?

Comment: @donRumata ни разу не работал с этой утилитой, но по описанию функционала есть что-то похожее. Проблема только в том, что у меня нет возможности инсталлировать на хост-машину новые пакеты, потому требуется скрипт

Comment: Каждый пятый рассказывает, что у него нет возможности установки. Правда потом выясняется, что или есть или он заходит внутрь докер контейнера и пишет `apt install`. Расскажи свою историю почему нельзя.

Comment: @donRumata требование компании-заказчика. ИБшники добавляют в локальные репозитории доступные пакеты для их систем самостоятельно. Сам процесс запроса на добавление новых пакетов неясен и никто не спешит этим заниматься в силу... даже не знаю в силу чего)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наличие файлов определённого типа(расширения) можно проверить простой командой `ls`. Допустим ваша папка для хранения бекапов `/bekap`, тип(расширение) файлов `.bkp`, тогда "триггер" проверки будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
ls /bekap/*.bkp &> /dev/null || echo fail
```

Эта команда выведет `fail` если в папке `/bekap` нет объектов содержащих `.bkp` в имени.

Answer (score 1):

Начните с прочтения доки по BASH:

https://linuxize.com/post/bash-if-else-statement/

https://linuxize.com/post/bash-check-if-file-exists/

Comment: Не стоит публиковать ссылки в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#Выйти из скрипта если команда закончилась ошибкой
set -e
#Перменные для путей и имени файла
fileName=archive.gz
oldDir="/y_backup"
latestDir="/latest_backup"

#Проверяем файл в каталоге последних бекапов
if [[ -f ${latestDir}/${fileName} ]]; then
#Проверяем файл в каталоге старых бэкапов
    if [[ -f ${oldDir}/${fileName} ]]; then
#Удаляем старый файл бекапа
         rm -f ${oldDir}/$fileName
    fi
#Перемещаем последний файл бекапа в папку со старыми бекапами
    mv ${latestDir}/$fileName ${oldDir}/$fileName
fi
#Тут команда для создания архива в каталоге последних бекапов
you command to create backup
```